# Calculating Prediction Interval

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

I have the following data located [here](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jtaylo/courses/stats203/data/oxygen.table). I am attempting to calculate the 95% confidence interval on the mean purity when the hydrocarbon percentage is 1.0. In R, I enter the following.

```
> predict(purity.lm, newdata=list(hydro=1.0), interval="confidence", level=.95)
   fit      lwr      upr
1 89.66431 87.51017 91.81845
```

However, how can I derive this result myself? I attempted to use the following equation.

$$s_{new}=\sqrt{s^2\left(1+\frac{1}{N}+\frac{(x_{new}-\bar x)^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}\right)}$$

And I enter the following in R.

```
> SSE_line = sum((purity - (77.863 + 11.801*hydro))^2)
> MSE = SSE_line/18
> t.quantiles <- qt(c(.025, .975), 18)
> prediction = B0 + B1*1
> SE_predict = sqrt(MSE)*sqrt(1+1/20+(mean(hydro)-1)^2/sum((hydro - mean(hydro))^2))
> prediction + SE_predict*t.quantiles
[1] 81.80716 97.52146
```

My results are different from R's predict function. What am I misunderstanding about prediction intervals?

Comment: How are you calculating the MSE in your code?

Comment: I added the calculation to the post.

Comment: as MMJ suggested you should try `predict(purity.lm, newdata=list(hydro=1.0), interval="prediction", level=.95)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `predict.lm` code is calculating confidence intervals for the fitted values. Your hand calculation is calculating prediction intervals for new data. If you want to get the same result from `predict.lm` that you got from the hand calculation then change  `interval="confidence"` to  `interval="prediction"`

Answer (score 2):

Good answer from dpel. I would add that the difference between confidence interval and prediction interval can be stated like below:

**Confidence interval**
$$ s_{new}=\sqrt{s^2\left(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{(x_{new}-\bar x)^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}\right)} $$

**Prediction interval**
$$ s_{new}=\sqrt{s^2\left(1+\frac{1}{N}+\frac{(x_{new}-\bar x)^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}\right)} $$

Source [See slide page 5/17 and 11/17](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~tjl13/s101/slides/unit6lec3H.pdf)